# How does setMaxResults(N) in Hibernate work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I am using MS SQL server 2008 with Hibernate. the question I have is how Hibernate implements `setMaxResults`

Take the following simple scenario.

If I have a query that returns 100 rows and if I pass 1 to `setMaxResults`, will this affect the returned result from the SQL server itself(as if running a `select top 1` statement) or does Hibernate get all the results first (all 100 rows in this case) and pick the top one itself?

Reason I am asking is that it would have a huge performance issue when the number of rows starts to grow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate will generate a limit-type query, for all dialects which supports limit query. As the SQLServerDialect supports this (see `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect.supportsLimit()`, and `.getLimitString()`), you will get a `select top 1`-query.

If you would like to be absolutly sure, you may turn on debug-logging, or enable the `showSql`-option and test.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. The thing is, I checked the  the debug output, it is indeed using `select top 1`.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL and I have printed the query. It does not have limit and it seems to get top 50 in my case after querying everything. Have you faced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

May be following snippet will help. Assume we have a managed Bean class EmpBean and we want only first 5 records. So following is the code

```
public List<EmpBean> getData()
{
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Query qry = session.createQuery("FROM EmpBean");
        qry.setMaxResults(5);
        return qry.list();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {}
    finally
    {           
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here getSession and closeSession are static utility methods which will take care of creating and closing session

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was looking for an explanation on how  `setMaxResults` is implemented behind the scene.Got the answer from @Aleksander Blomskøld's reply.