# Does Hibernate SQLQuery restrict the results with native features when using setMaxResults to limit results

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

When using SQLQuery with setMaxResults() method to limit the number of records returned,
does hibernate limit the results using the native features of database like top or limit keywords or does hibernate limit the results at the library layer after all the results are returned?

Thanks,
Keshav

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125824/how-does-setmaxresultsn-in-hibernate-work

Comment: query itself tuned to fetch only certain records set in the method setMaxResults()!

Comment: I think it uses the sql native features.

Comment: check this url your will find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query

Comment: Actually i am not using a HQL here its a SQLQuery with native query, and SQLQuery has a provisioin to setMaxResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of records returned is done at the query level. It uses database keywords like limit to restrict the number of rows returned.

You  can also turn on the hibernate.show_sql fetature and see the generated query.

Code:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM REQUEST_T");
sqlQuery.setMaxResults(10);
List results = sqlQuery.list();
```

Hibernate Generated Query:

/* dynamic native SQL query */

SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        REQUEST_T limit ?

Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */

SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        REQUEST_T limit ?

Comment: Actually i am not using a HQL, with HQL hibernate generates query and it has provision to tweak it as it wants. But then  here its a SQLQuery with native query, and SQLQuery has a provisioin to setMaxResults

Comment: I have updated the answer that contains an example code snippet and the hibernate generated query taken from the logs.